# Editing comma delimited cell in Google Sheets to replace some items

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell that contains mixed input of one or more delimited items eg:

`apple,ABC1,banana,BBC2,FGC3`

I need to replace the items that contain ALPHA code eg `ABC1` (from a finite list of about 25 codes)

with a new sequence (eg `ABC1` becomes `avocado,apricot,carrot`, eg `BBC2` becomes `plum,damson,leek`)

so that the new output looks like this

`apple,avocado,apricot,carrot,banana,plum,damson,leek...` etc

Can I do this with a formula?

I've tried `switch` and `if` but these only change the entire cell when a single item gets matched...

```
=SWITCH(Q2, 
"ABC1", "avocado,apricot,carrot",
"BBC2", "plum,damson,leek"
)
```

EDIT - thanks for feedback already, more info will be helpful here... This cell is in one column of about 400 rows, and I'm looking at creating a formula that can iterate through all rows. Also the number of delimited items in each cell varies (eg the next row might look like this: `ABC1,banana`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with nested `SUBSTITUTE` formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            Q2, "ABC1", "avocado,apricot,carrot"),
                "BBC2", "plum,damson,leek"),
                "XYZ7", "cherry,fig,date")
```

Just kept iterating on nesting x 25.

Thanks everyone for input

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
                 REGEXREPLACE(N1:N3,"(ABC1)","xxx,XXX,xx"), 
                                    "(BBC2)","z,zz,xyz"))
```

[image]

*(you should to adjust ranges and values to your needs)*

---

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: This looks promising - how would it work with 25 exchanges to make? Would I keep nesting `REGXREPLACE(` x25? Not having much luck with that implementation...

Comment: *"Would I keep nesting `REGXREPLACE`...?"*  Yes. **Or** -as you already found out- by nesting  `SUBSTITUTE`. 
*"Thanks everyone for input"*. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off:

Select the cells you want to change (don't select if you want this to be done for all cells), then press Ctrl+H (Search and replace), then for the example that you have given:

Find: ABC1

Replace: avocado,apricot,carrot

Comment: Thanks for feedback - its not a one off, but will be needed on over 400 rows, each with one or more entries (!) So, looking for an iterative approach...

Comment: added EDIT to question to provide more info. Again, thanks

Comment: I think @Bijan Riazi-Farzad was referring to your need to do this a single time, or again and again in the future. Find and replace will have no trouble with 400 cells.

Comment: understood @Phil Anderson, thanks for clarifying. It was indeed an automation I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this consistently, then here is a workaround:

Let's assume that [apple,ABC1,banana,BBC2,FGC3] is in cell D4

E5: [=left(D4,find("ABC1",D4)-1)]

F5: [avocado,apricot,carrot]

G5: [=right(D5,(len(D5)-len(E5)-4))]

H5: [=E5&F5&G5]

Once you see the logic behind this, you can combine the above into one formula in one cell and it will look like this:

[=left(D4,find("ABC1",D4)-1)&"avocado,apricot,carrot"&right(D4,find("ABC1",D4)+4)]

Where the "4" at the end of the formula is the length of the string that you are replacing (in this case "ABC1")

Comment: Again thanks for this workaround, but I'm looking at having one formula that I can iterate for each row. Also, the number of items varies too...

Comment: added EDIT to question to provide more info. Again, thanks

Comment: Thanks for further update - however ```=left(D4,find("ABC1",D4)-1)&"avocado,apricot,carrot"&right(D4,find("ABC1",D4)+4)``` results in `avocado,apricot,carrotABC1`...